# Uicalendar in Matlab is not worked in deployment

Tags: matlab, ui-calendar

I am creating a Matlab GUI model. Everything is working perfectly in executable deployment excepts for **uicalendar** function. My idea is want to use **uicalendar** to pick up for a specific date, it works properly in Matlab program but none working for deployment (.exe). I learn that uicalendar was not supported for building an executable file in Matlab. Do you know any options to pickup for a date in Matlab GUI, which can work in deployment platform?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try some of the other calendars that are on the Mathworks FEX

[uigetdate](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8313-uigetdate)

[yet another calendar](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15913-yet-another-calendar?s_tid=FX_rc1_behav)

[datepicker](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31387-datepicker?s_tid=FX_rc2_behav)

Note: I am not the author of any of these.

Comment: Thanks, i tried three of these but it difficult to get value after selected data.